# How do I modify the following callback function so it returns a promise?

Tags: javascript, promise

This function tries to load an image, if the image doesn't loads, the function is called again:

```
function loadImage (url = '', callback = () => {}) {
  utils.loadImage(url, () => {
    callback()
  }, () => {
    loadImage(url, callback)
  })
}
```

I want it to return I promise so I wrote:

```
function loadImage (url = '', callback = () => {}) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    utils.loadImage(url, () => {
      // what to do with resolve and reject
      callback()
    }, () => {
      loadImage(url, callback)
    })
  })
}
```

But I'm not sure where to place resolve and reject ...

Comment: Looks fine... have you tried? Those parameters are not needed if you're not going to process them

Comment: Drop the `callback` parameter, and call `resolve` instead.

Comment: You really should already promisify `utils.loadImage` if that's under your control

Comment: Did you have a look at [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22519784/1048572)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const loadImage = url => new Promise(resolve => {
  utils.loadImage(url, resolve, () => {
    loadImage(url).then(resolve)
  })
})
```

Edit: Even better version thanks to Bergi's comment:

```
const loadImage = url => new Promise(resolve => {
  utils.loadImage(url, resolve, () => resolve(loadImage(url)))
})
```

Comment: Or best: `const loadImage = url => new Promise((resolve, reject) => utils.loadImage(url, resolve, reject).catch(() => loadImage(url))`